# Performance issue of flatList in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I've tried flatlist but it has a bit of performance issues in android.

1. As I scroll down, it loads the list. But afterwards, it shows blank while scrolling upwards.
2. After reaching the end of the screen, it stops for a while and then loads the datas. Why is it not showing loader (activity indicator) at the bottom? Why is onEndReached and onEndReachedThreshold not working?

Plz have a look at the video [here](https://youtu.be/5tkkEAUEAHM)

https://youtu.be/5tkkEAUEAHM

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
import { List, ListItem, SearchBar } from "react-native-elements";

export default class FlatListExample extends Component
{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      data: [],
      page: 1,
      seed: 1,
      error: null,
      refreshing: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.makeRemoteRequest();
  }

  makeRemoteRequest = () => {
    const { page, seed } = this.state;
    const url = `https://randomuser.me/api/?seed=${seed}&page=${page}&results=20`;
    console.log('url', url);
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    setTimeout(()=>{
      fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          this.setState({
            data:  [...this.state.data, ...res.results],
            error: res.error || null,
            loading: false,
            refreshing: false
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.setState({ error, loading: false });
        });
    },0);

  };

  renderFooter = () => {
    if (!this.state.loading) return null;

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          paddingVertical: 20,
          borderTopWidth: 1,
          borderColor: "#CED0CE"
        }}
      >
        <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  };

handleLoadMore = () =>{
  this.setState({
    page:this.state.page + 1,
  },()=>{
    this.makeRemoteRequest();
  })
}
  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <ListItem
            roundAvatar
            title={`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}
            subtitle={item.email}
            avatar={{ uri: item.picture.thumbnail }}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item.email}
        ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
        onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
        onEndReachedThreshold={50}
      />
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('FlatListExample', () => FlatListExample);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've noticed that you're not setting `initialNumToRender`. From the docs:

> initialNumToRender: number
>
> How many items to render in the initial batch. This should be enough
>   to fill the screen but not much more. Note these items will never be
>   unmounted as part of the windowed rendering in order to improve
>   perceived performance of scroll-to-top actions.

So you'll want to estimate how many cells you expect to be visible at any given time and set it to that. I'd also recommend if you haven't already to update to the latest react-native which includes various improvements on the FlatList component.

Comment: Thanks sooper. I've the latest version- 'react-native: 0.44.0'. initialNumToRender solves the blank issue. But I have 1 more problem. When the scroll reach end of the screen, it's taking a bit of a time to load the data. Infinite scroll is not working well. Sometime a loader is seen but it doesn't most of the time. onEndReached and onEndReachedThreshold not working well. https://youtu.be/rTw935FURQY

Comment: You may want to check out the issues on the react-navigation project and see if anyone else is experiencing the same

Comment: 0.44.1 is now available, and includes [this fix](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/22a4205bdd63d60c7d7290693aaccfe47e84ebb3)